# How do you set links for the same page?

Tags: php, html

Im looking to make a simple text-based game, and i was wondering how you set links for actions to be on the same page, so you wouldnt have to be redirected to a different page. So basically i just want everything in the game to be on one page, jus not all displayed at once.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you create a html site? Use javascript to hide parts of your website.

Comment: its in php, you have to be logged in to play it, does that matter?

Comment: Try using (jQuery) AJAX.

Comment: please explain in more detail what you want to do. What do you mean by "action" exactly - are those JavaScript function calls, hashes (`#xyz`) or something else? Maybe show some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to avoid lots of different php files on the server for every page of the game, then pass a variable to php.  E.g. the URL `game.php?page=start` would set the variable `$_REQUEST['page']` in your php script and you can make a condition based off of that.

If you are trying to avoid the page refreshing, then AJAX is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to call other components of the page. It's the best way to manipulate a page without refresh.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jsonp.

what is jsonp :

> JSONP is script tag injection, passing the response from the server in to a user specified function

see links:

- http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

also you can use jQuery.getJSON() to give data from jsonp

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to refresh the page, but this time with new variables. If your page is called game.php, and you are updating the health:

```
$health = $_REQUEST['health'];
$health++;
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='game.php?health=$health'>";
```

This will constantly refresh the page, increasing the health by 1 every time.